# iReport 4.5.1 throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Getting following error message while loading ***iReport 4.5.1*** new install:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3184
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileChooserIcon(Win32ShellFolder2.java:748)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.get(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:248)
at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(ShellFolder.java:221)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel$LazyWindowsIcon.createValue(WindowsLookAndFeel.java:1873)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getFromHashtable(UIDefaults.java:185)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.get(UIDefaults.java:130)
at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.get(MultiUIDefaults.java:44)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getIcon(UIDefaults.java:411)
at javax.swing.UIManager.getIcon(UIManager.java:613)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.installIcons(BasicFileChooserUI.java:237)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.installDefaults(BasicFileChooserUI.java:219)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.installUI(BasicFileChooserUI.java:135)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.installUI(WindowsFileChooserUI.java:126)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:653)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI(JFileChooser.java:1755)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setup(JFileChooser.java:366)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:341)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:300)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.options.IReportPanel.jButtonAddClasspathItemActionPerformed(IReportPanel.java:2216)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.options.IReportPanel.access$2000(IReportPanel.java:84)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.options.IReportPanel$27.actionPerformed(IReportPanel.java:938)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1849)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2169)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5501)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3135)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5266)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3968)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3803)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3892)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1778)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3803)
[catch] at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known issue for *iReport* running on ***Vista*** or ***Windows 7***.

You can try to upgrade your JVM to 1.7 (in some cases the 1.6) version.

For more details you can read this posts on [JasperForge.org](http://jasperforge.org):

- [Unable to "Add Folder" to the Options -> Classpath](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=69115)
- [Error java 3184 when trying to open a document](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=71460)

***UPDATE:***

You can set the JDK for iReport via ***`ireport.conf`*** file in *`iReport-x.y.z\etc`* folder. With help of `jdkhome` property we can set the JDK path.

The sample:

```
jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

Comment: Iam using windows 7 and JVM 1.7 is installed all the issue started with this when I did a fresh install in my new computer...**Warning - could not install some modules: HadoopHive - The Java platform version 1.6 or higher was requested but only 1.5 is running. MongoDbPlugin - The Java platform version 1.6 or higher was requested but only 1.5 is running.** and when I licked ok on this error message I got the other error message listed above.....

Comment: You can try to modify *`ireport.conf`* file in *`iReport-4.5.1\etc`* folder. # default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"

Comment: It is looks like your iReport is running under JVM 1.5

Comment: Alex thanks after I changed the JDK this issue got resolved.... am able to proceed with out any issues....

Comment: upgrade the Java Version JDK to 1.7 and try again, or try 1.8 if error persists.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that this problem might be caused by something else than JDK version. I'm running iReport 4.5.1 on windows 7 and tried JDK 1.6 and 1.7 getting the same error. Than I found that problem is related to some fields retrived by SQL statement (Stored Procedure in mssql 2008 R2). Problem was ntext field casted to java.lang.String. I changed field class to java.sql.Clouds and found that report is generated (but this column is unreadable). When I was messing with different types I found that the problem was column width. As my procedure retrives many parameters I have many "thin" columns in design generated by wizard. When I resize (enlarge) ntext result column on the layout and click "preview" everything is fine, when column is to thin to fill data (one letter width, because wraps are correct) I'm getting this error: 
Error filling print... 0 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 
I've tested it few times, so without any doubt this was the problem in my case not JDK.